# Функция не изменяет элементы массива

Tags: c++

Есть двумерный динамический массив. Мне нужно, чтобы цикл прошел по всему массиву, при этом останавливался на требуемый мне элементах и применял функцию, которая изменяет рандомно либо следующий элемент в строке, либо следующий элемент в столбце. Но он не делает вообще ничего. При этом, если я меняю в функции i + 1 и j + 1 на i - 1 и j -1 (i и j - счетчики в цикле, координаты в массиве), она начинает работать, но не делает то, что мне нужно.

```
#include <ctime>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int change(int **array, int i, int j, int x, int r) {
    bool ch = false;
    if ((i == x - 2) || (j == x - 2)) {
        if ((i == x - 1) && (j == x - 2)) {
            ch = true;
        }
        if ((ch == false) && (i == x - 2)) {
            array[i][j + 1] = 0;
            ch = true;
        }
        if ((ch == false) && (j == x - 2)) {
            array[i + 1][j] = 0;
            ch = true;
        }
    }
    if (ch == false) {
        if (r == 0) {
            array[i + 1][j] = 0;
        }
        else {
      array[i][j + 1] = 0;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

int main() {
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "rus");
  srand(time(0));
    int x, y;
    cin >> x;
    while ((x % 2 == 0) || (x <= 5)) {
        cout << "введите нечетное число, большее 5" << endl;
        cin >> x;
    }
    y = x;
    int **array = new int *[x];
    for (int i = 0; i < x; i++) {
        array[i] = new int[y];
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < x; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < x; j++) {
            array[i][j] = 1;
            if ((i % 2 == 1) && (j % 2 == 1)) {
                array[i][j] = 0;
        int r = rand() % 2;
                change(array, i, j, x,r);
            }
        }
    } 

    for (int i = 0; i < x; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < x; j++) {
            cout << array[i][j] << ' ';
        }
        cout << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: дебажить не пробовали?

Comment: я не знаю что должна делать функция change, но там ch будет всегда true, условие `if (ch == false)` никогда не будет выполнено. и ещё нет проверок на выходы за пределы массива.

Comment: @segray а где должна быть проверка за пределы массива? На самом деле не знаю, как донести, что делает функция, не расписывая условие задачи. Не понимаю, почему ch всегда будет true? Как раз оказалось, что с ch проблем нет и ch == false выполняется.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вообще у вас заполнение массива и его последующее изменение сделано в одном цикле, когда часть элементов еще не инициализировано/заполнено

```
for (int i = 0; i < x; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < x; j++) {
        array[i][j] = 1;
        if ((i % 2 == 1) && (j % 2 == 1)) {
            array[i][j] = 0;
    int r = rand() % 2;
            change(array, i, j, x,r);
        }
    }
}
```

Разделите эти 2 этапа

```
// заполняем массив
for (int i = 0; i < x; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < x; j++) {
        array[i][j] = 1;
        if ((i % 2 == 1) && (j % 2 == 1)) {
            array[i][j] = 0;
        }
    }
}

// модифицируем массив
for (int i = 0; i < x; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < x; j++) {
        if ((i % 2 == 1) && (j % 2 == 1)) {
            int r = rand() % 2;
            change(array, i, j, x, r);
        }
    }
}
```

P.S.

ну и вообще по коду -

1. вы сначала пишите, что вы хотите от пользователя, а то у вас ввод ожидается без каких либо надписей

вместо

```
cin >> x;
while ((x % 2 == 0) || (x <= 5)) {
    cout << "введите нечетное число, большее 5" << endl;
    cin >> x;
}
```

лучше

```
do {
    cout << "введите нечетное число, большее 5" << endl;
    cin >> x;
} while ((x % 2 == 0) || (x <= 5));
```